# Group by grouping sets in BigQuery vs Teradata

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, teradata

Does BigQuery have the same functionality to `group by GROUPING SETS` in Teradata?

For example in Teradata we can use something like that

```
group   by GROUPING SETS ( (1,2,3,4,5,6 ), (1,2,4,5,6 ))
```

Is it possible in BigQuery?

Comment: `GROUPING SETS` is not available in BigQuery! also see [Migrating Teradata to BigQuery: SQL translation reference](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migration/dw2bq/td2bq/td-bq-sql-translation-reference-tables) , Meantime if you provide specific use case we might be able to help with it

Comment: You can always rewrite *Extended Grouping* using `UNION ALL`, of course, it might be slower.

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery has rollup, but not `grouping sets`.  For your particular example:

```
group by 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 rollup (4)
```

However, it is not as general as `grouping sets`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, am getting an error "Expected end of input but got keyword WITH"

Comment: ROLLUP is supported only if you have a single grouping element

Comment: @JohnDilinjer . . . That error must be somewhere else in the statement, because he `group by` clause has no `with`.

Answer (score 0):

One more option to elaborate from one of the above examples, when you need aggregated stats like sum, min,max etc

```
with table as (select 'au' dim1, 'samsung' dim2, 'browser1' dim3 , 100 clk, 10000 e
union all
select 'ind' c, 'iphone' d, 'browser2' b , 1000 clk, 10000 e
union all
select 'ind' c, 'samsung' d, 'browser2' b , 10 clk, 1 e)

select 
     dim1
    ,dim2
    ,dim3
    ,max(clk)clk
    ,max(e) e
    from
(SELECT 

     dim1
    ,dim2
    ,dim3
    ,sum(clk) over (partition by dim1,dim2,dim3) clk
    ,sum(e) over (partition by dim1,dim2,dim3) e
FROM table,
UNNEST ([dim1, 'ALL']) AS dim1,
UNNEST ([dim2, 'ALL']) AS dim2,
UNNEST ([dim3, 'ALL']) AS dim3
)
GROUP BY dim1,dim2,dim3
```